# Running a line from a terminal for QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows, gdalbuildvrt

I am trying to run this code:

```
# create virtual multi-band raster 
gdalbuildvrt -separate rgb.vrt red.tif green.tif blue.tif
# write multi-band raster into geotiff
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB rgb.vrt rgb.tif
```

I want to know how to be able to do this in a terminal outside of QGIS.

Comment: You could use **OSGeo4W Shell** command prompt.

Comment: I am unsure on how to do that.  Is this within QGIS in the Python Console?

Comment: It's a separate program which you should be able to find in your _Start_ menu (e.g. `Start > All Programs > QGIS 2.18 > OSGeo4W Shell`. If your paths have been configured correctly, you should be able to use your gdal commands directly: `gdalbuildvrt -separate path/to/rgb.vrt path/to/red.tif path/to/green.tif path/to/blue.tif`